# Child projects not showing up in Rally

Tags: rally

I have this code:

```
 var projectStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore',{
        model: 'project',
        fetch: ['Name','ObjectID'],
        autoLoad: true,
        context:{
            project: '/project/33086603461',
            projectScopeDown: true,
            projectScopeUp:false
        },

            listeners:{
            load: function(store,records,success){
                console.log('store ',records);
            },
            scope: this
        }
});
```

When I print the store , it is showing up all the projects instead of just the project with the given object ID and its children. How do I access only the children of the given project?

Answer (score 0):

The project endpoint in WSAPI is a little different in that it does not obey the project/projectScopeUp/projectScopeDown parameters.

You should just add a filter to your store referencing the parent project instead:

```
var projectStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore',{
    model: 'project',
    fetch: ['Name','ObjectID'],
    autoLoad: true,
    filters: [{
        property: 'Parent',
        operator: '=',
        value: '/project/33086603461'
    }],
    listeners:{
        load: function(store,records,success){
            console.log('store ',records);
        },
        scope: this
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes I did exactly that. Works like a charm. Thank you. :)